# Accessing nested JSON objects and arrays within objects to display in HTML - AngularJS

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs, json, object

I'm having trouble trying to pull through specific values within nested JSON data, I have been searching endlessly and tried lots of different routes but to no avail. Basically I would like to take all the instances of 'summary' and display them as instructions (list items) like this:

- Metropolitan line to Finchley Road
- Jubilee line to Waterloo

I'm still a newbie to AngularJS so any help is much appreciated, I think I may be way over complicating it.

JSON

```
{
"$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.ItineraryResult, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
"journeys": [
    {
        "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.Journey, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
        "startDateTime": "2019-03-11T21:22:00",
        "duration": 49,
        "arrivalDateTime": "2019-03-11T22:11:00",
        "legs": [
            {
                "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.Leg, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
                "duration": 34,
                "instruction": {
                    "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Instruction, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
                    "summary": "Metropolitan line to Finchley Road",
                    "detailed": "Metropolitan line towards Aldgate",
                    "steps": []
                },
            },
            {
                "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.Leg, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
                "duration": 13,
                "instruction": {
                    "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Instruction, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
                    "summary": "Jubilee line to Waterloo",
                    "detailed": "Jubilee line towards Stratford",
                    "steps": []
                },
                ],
            }
        ]
```

HTML

```
<ul ng-repeat="x in data.journeys[0]">

    <li ng-repeat="y in x.legs[0]">{{y.instruction.summary}}</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Do you get correct number of `li` in your page? Because your outer repeat is on `journeys[0]`, this seems incorrect to me. It should be just data.journeys. Same with x.legs. It should be just x.legs and not x.legs[0]

Comment: Thanks @PM, I took out [0] which displays data but also shows 'journeys' from further down the JSON. I only need the top instance, changing the code to `x in data.journeys | limitTo : 1` seems to work but is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Marc, I think that's the correct way if you always want to have just the top instance of journey from the journeys. Another way could be to have `<li ng-repeat="y in data.journeys[0].legs">` But to me your current approach looks better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ng-repeat over data.journeys not data.journeys[0].

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);
app.controller("Cont", function($scope) {
$scope.data =  {
  "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.ItineraryResult, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
  "journeys": [
    {
      "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.Journey, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
      "startDateTime": "2019-03-11T21:22:00",
      "duration": 49,
      "arrivalDateTime": "2019-03-11T22:11:00",
      "legs": [
        {
          "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.Leg, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
          "duration": 34,
          "instruction": {
            "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Instruction, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "summary": "Metropolitan line to Finchley Road",
            "detailed": "Metropolitan line towards Aldgate",
            "steps": []
          }
        },
        {
          "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.Leg, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
          "duration": 13,
          "instruction": {
            "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Instruction, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "summary": "Jubilee line to Waterloo",
            "detailed": "Jubilee line towards Stratford",
            "steps": []
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Cont">
  <ul ng-repeat="x in data.journeys">
    <li ng-repeat="y in x.legs">{{y.instruction.summary}}</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan, that has displayed some data but more than I wanted. There are actually more instances of 'journey' further down the JSON so it is displaying these as well, I only want to show the top one. If I do `x in data.journeys | limitTo : 1` that seems to work, but is it the best way?